# How to create a datasource in JBoss with different driver version

Tags: jdbc, jboss, datasource, jboss-4.2.x

I have an installation of JBoss (4.3.0) with the version 9.0.2.0 of the Oracle driver in the lib directory. I would like to create a datasource that uses a newer version of the driver, without changing the common configuration (many other applications depend on it and should be tested again). Unfortunately I can not even use a connection pool inside the application as this will cause a PermGen memory leak at every redeploy (evidently the context does not unload the driver when it is closed). is it possible?

Comment: The Driver class name remains the same across all the used versions of the Oracle driver, right? What are the versions? Anywhere I can download them to check?

Comment: Yes the Oracle class name are the same. The version in the configuration dir is 9.0.2 but for this datasource I need 11.x.